# How to restart a PHP script when server connection is lost

Tags: php, error-handling, server, xmlhttprequest

I have written a script that retrieves data from online databases. But sometimes the connection of the internet or the connection with the server is lost. When I got this, the script stops running.

I think when the internet connection is lost, there is no error, the script just stops. And I think when the server connection is lost I got an "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server" warning. I got this warning when I perform

```
file_get_contents($xml)
```

Is there a way to restart the script from the point where the warning or stop occurs? If not, how do you restart the script from the beginning?
Or is it only possible with cron jobs?

Comment: See the ignore_user_abort directive : [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) it should give you the solution to your problem